# background images are grainy and slow with iOS 8, iphone 5s

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, ios8

My client asked me to put a bunch of random background images on his iPhone app. So it's set up by putting a UIImageView on top of self.view, adding an FXBlurView on top of that (for blurring purposes, obviously), then putting a UIScrollView on top of THAT, and laying translucent UIViews containing control objects on top of all of it. it looks something like the yahoo weather app when all is said and done. my question is twofold. now that i've explained the situation, here are my two questions:

**Question 1**

the background images are very grainy. what size should they be for an iphone 5? and what size for an iPhone 6? i thought retina was 640x1136, which should be the minimum size right? why is it only showing the entire image for 320x568? from what i've read, they should be the following for a 5s:

```
320 x 568
640 x 1136
960 x 1704
```

when i do that, they appear very grainy. if i do any larger than that then the pictures are cut off. the whole picture isn't being shown.

**Question 2**

In iOS 7, the app ran fantastically. now that iOS 8 is out, the scrolling graphics are slow and choppy. I took the background image out completely and it sped right back up. I'm wondering what i can do to speed the scrolling up again with a background image staying stationery while the control objects scroll.

any ideas for me?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to the first question**

apple has you design your apps at 320x568. The extra pixels are used to make the text and images look sharper. Otherwise, everything would be smaller on a retina display and not sharper.

So you don't have direct control over that extra retina space. The iPhone uses it to digitally make the images sharper and clearer.

**I'd still like to know why its choppy and the graphics are poor while scrolling**

Answer (score 0):

I use FXBlurView as well, and found that turning the dynamic option of the blur view to OFF fixes the issue. For some reason on iOS 8 FXBlurView uses 100% CPU when dynamic is ON.